# JMeter writing a variable to the log ONCE during a test fragment

Tags: performance, jmeter, load-testing

Working on a load test of our website.

I have several test fragments that I include in my main test plan.
In the main test plan I set parameters to how long the thread should (pause in the different test fragments), before moving on.

I would like to write to the console what we're waiting for, but the problem is that I can't find a way to log to the console ONCE in the test fragment.

This is what I currently have in my fragment:

BeanShell PostProcessor

```
log.info("### User is interacting with the GLASSES-page for: " + vars.get("glassesSpentTime") + "ms")
```

In the console I then see a log message per HTTP request:

```
jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: ### User is interacting with the GLASSES-page for: 37000ms 
jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: ### User is interacting with the GLASSES-page for: 37000ms 
jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: ### User is interacting with the GLASSES-page for: 37000ms
```

And so on...

I only want to have this message in the log ONCE. 
What can I use to send one log message in my test fragments?

Thanks!

/J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post processor should be the child element of the HTTP request which requires post processing. If in the same level as the HTTP request, JMeter assumes that all the HTTP requests requires post processing & invoke that.

As you might know, each thread will execute the entire thread group separately. So, if there are 3 users, then you will 3 log messages. To avoid this confusion you might want to add,

```
log.info("### User${__threadNum} - is interacting with the GLASSES-page for: " + vars.get("glassesSpentTime") + "ms")
```

Youwill get the log as shown here.

```
jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: ### User1 - is interacting with the GLASSES-page for: 37000ms  
jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: ### User2 - is interacting with the GLASSES-page for: 37000ms  
jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: ### User3 - is interacting with the GLASSES-page for: 37000ms
```

Comment: Awesome! I'm a JMeter noob so I very much appreciate your input. I'll try it out and mark your answer if/when it works out.